# Detecting post type within init action

Tags: ajax, hooks, redirect, login

I have an front-end ajax login on my site.  I want to set the redirect url to `'/services/clientarea';` for every page that is not part of the blog.  For blog pages i want the login redirect to be `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Here is the code that I'm using which isn't working for me:

```
function ajax_login_init(){

wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

global  $post;
$posttype = get_post_type($post);

if ($posttype == 'post') {
    $loginredirect = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
} else {
    $loginredirect = '/services/clientarea';
}

wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => $loginredirect,
    'loadingmessage' => __('Signing in, please wait...')
));

// Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}

// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
}
```

It seems that the post type isn't loaded in the init hook.  Is there any way to identify it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, let's get some thing staight first.

Here is list of [actions run during typical request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request). It goes like this:

- ...
- init
- ...
- parse_request
- ...
- parse_query
- pre_get_posts
- posts_selection
- ...
- wp

As you can see, posts are selected much later after init. To be more precise, even the request is parsed after init hook. So there is no easy way to get `$post` in `init` action, I'm afraid.

If you move your code from `init` to `wp` (or later), then you can get `$post` from `$wp_query` object.

But... I'm not sure if I understand, what are you trying to achieve with this code. If you hook your AJAX action based on queried post, it won't fire up at all, I guess. Why? AJAX call is another request (`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`) so there won't be any `$post` retrieved in this request, so your action won't get hooked, so it won't fire up.

I'm pretty sure this is what you really want:

```
function enqueue_ajax_login_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

    // check if it's single post
    if ( is_singular('post') ) {
        $loginredirect = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    } else {
        $loginredirect = '/services/clientarea';
    }

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => $loginredirect,
        'loadingmessage' => __('Signing in, please wait...')
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ajax_login_scripts');

// it can be registered every time (it won't fire up unless there will be such AJAX request
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I thought it would be something like this.  I only want the 'redirect url' parameter of the ajax_login_object to differ depending on which page is being loaded.  As this is parameter is set in php I thought it could be modified before the page is served.  Trouble is, my ajax_login_init function doesn't seem to work unless hooked in with the init action.

Comment: I added some code to my answer. I'm pretty sure this is what you really want to do.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much except it needs to check not only if it's a single post but if its index.php, post archive or any page that displays blog posts so I'm still going to use global  $post; $posttype = get_post_type($post); if ($posttype == 'post') to check.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: P.S. It's been educational too :-)

Answer (score 2):

While @krzysiek [Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142533/4130) is the correct method to follow when enqueing files, don't answer the original question of how to get post type at init hook so I'm posting the solution in here in case anyone needs it.

Basically you can't access the post variable at that hook so you need to get it by using the url. The [url_to_postid()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) is the function you need to use and you can do something like this:

```
$actual_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$post_id = url_to_postid($actual_url);
$post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
```

This is just a workaround in case you need it, but would be better to start messing at wp hook where the variables are already set.

Comment: The only problem with you code is that url_to_postid might not return valid post ID, but you ignore it ;)